# Log4j 1.x Sentry appender: suppress warnings from specific sources for one appender

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, sentry

I'm using a Log4j 1.x appender for Sentry to track error logging.

I'd like to ignore warnings from certain sources, e.g. from the logger `dre.mytest`. Can I do this using the log4j.properties file? Currently it looks like this.

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, Sentry

# Configure the Sentry appender, overriding the logging threshold to the WARN level
log4j.appender.Sentry=com.getsentry.raven.log4j.SentryAppender
log4j.appender.Sentry.threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.Sentry.tags=system:annotator
```

I tried

```
log4j.logger.dre.mytest=INFO, stdout
log4j.logger.dre.mytest=ERROR, Sentry
```

but this doesn't log anything lower than error to stdout.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using another appender:

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, SentryWarn

# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Configure Sentry appenders, each with their own threshold
log4j.appender.SentryInfo=com.getsentry.raven.log4j.SentryAppender
log4j.appender.SentryInfo.threshold=INFO
log4j.appender.SentryInfo.tags=system:app

log4j.appender.SentryWarn=com.getsentry.raven.log4j.SentryAppender
log4j.appender.SentryWarn.threshold=WARN
log4j.appender.SentryWarn.tags=system:app

log4j.appender.SentryError=com.getsentry.raven.log4j.SentryAppender
log4j.appender.SentryError.threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.SentryError.tags=system:app

# To suppress warnings from loggers to Sentry, use the following
# log4j.logger.<your-logger-here>=INFO, stdout, SentryError
# log4j.additivity.<your-logger-here> = false

# To send info and higher to Sentry, use the following
# log4j.logger.dre.mytest=INFO, stdout, SentryInfo
# log4j.additivity.dre.mytest = false
```

After upgrading to Log4j 2 it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN"
               packages="org.apache.logging.log4j.core,com.getsentry.raven.log4j2">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n"/>
        </Console>
        <Raven name="Sentry">
            <tags>system:app</tags>
        </Raven>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Sentry" level="warn"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="dre.test"
                level="INFO"
                additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Sentry" level="error"/>
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```